Cloud Function Upload CSV from GCS to BigQuery
I have a CSV that a user is uploading into GCS. A cloud function is triggered to read the CSV and dump it into a BQ table (all fields as STRING so not to throw an error when loading).
When I use one CSV the process works flawlessly. Logs are:
file_name.csv found
Starting file load from [gs://bucket-name/file_name.csv] to [project.dataset_name.file_name]
Successfully loaded 594 rows to [project.dataset_name.file_name]

However, when I use another CSV I get an error
new_file_name.csv found
Starting file load from [gs://bucket-name/new_file_name.csv] to [project.dataset_name.new_file_name]

google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Provided Schema does not match Table project.dataset_name.new_file_name. Cannot add fields (field: uuid); reason: invalid, message: Provided Schema does not match Table project.dataset_name.new_file_name. Cannot add fields (field: uuid)

The error occurs when calling bq_client.load_table_from_uri(source_uris=uri, destination=table_name, job_config=job_config).result().
What's confusing is that neither the CSV nor BQ table have a uuid column.
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

I have printed out the full schema of BQ table with bq show --schema dataset_name.new_file_name and don't see any uuid.
I have printed the header row of the CSV and it doesn't include any uuid field.
I have printed the full job_config being used and no uuid field exists in the whole object.

NEW_FILE_NAME_job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("field1", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("field2", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("field3", "STRING"),
        ... <no uuid field>
        ],
    skip_leading_rows=1,
    source_format="CSV"
)

I'm lost on where that error message could be generated from. Is there some background process that BQ is executing during load_table_from_uri that generates a uuid? Could there be a hidden phantom column on the BQ table? I'm not sure what else to troubleshoot.

The error message you are getting is indeed a bit tricky due to the 'uuid'. Make sure to check your schema thoroughly as there might be hidden columns or header mismatch in your CSV file.
Here's a couple of related references you can explore:

Load batch CSV Files from Cloud Storage to BigQuery and append on same table

Loading CSV data from Cloud Storage


